# How to Authenticate User that is coming to our web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I do have a requirement such as on Forgot Password Link one email is sent to the User with a link as CLICK HERE for reset the password.On click it must redirect to our web site having 2 text boxes as New Password and Confirm Password.
So how would i know that it is the User who have clicked before while Forget Password.

Comment: You have two options: a) require some information that only the user will known (eg. some personal document) or b) send a unique link to each forgot password request (this is what most websites do)

Comment: @tucaz Or both, sometimes they ask for personal details before sending the link.

Comment: @jumpingcode sure! why not?

Comment: Is this can be achieved by using GUID in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard here is you create a temporary token to reset the password. Here is the methodology.

1. User clicks on "forgot password" page after trying to log in
2. Token created for account and stored in database
3. Email sent to user with URI that includes the token. Example: mysite.com/forgotPassword.aspx?id=EDAB19D243
4. User clicks email link
5. User asked security question(s) from account, like "what is your father's middle name?"
6. If user successfully answers security questions, he is allowed to change password

The idea here is a multi-factor approach to making sure user is the correct user. Security provisions:

- Token only good for a period of time (stated in email)
- Token only sent to user (not displayed on web page)
- User must answer other questions about account - security questions are better than address, phone number, birthdate, as someone stealing identity will know the answer to those questions